# create a .bat file and run multiple command with call

Tags: batch-file, command, npm-install

I want to run some command in the batch file and use the if statement.

```
@echo off
call npm install
echo node js instaled
if not errorlevel 1 (
    call composer install
    if not errorlevel 1 (
        echo commands run success.
    ) else (
        echo please install composer and then run this batch again.
    )
) else (
    echo you have not nodejs in your system. please install nodejs.
)
```

when I run this batch file after npm install completed say

```
node js installed
if was unexpected at this time.
```

how I can check success and unsuccess of the command and then run other commands.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give this a try:

```
@echo off
call npm install && (
    echo node js installed
    call composer install && (
       echo Composer installed
    ) || echo composer install failed
) || echo Nodejs install failed
```

`&&` is conditional, if the first command was successful, then run the next. `||` is then becoming the `else` operator.